# Intellij Local History Does Not Allow Edit

Tags: intellij-idea

When I look at the local history of an individual file, my current file is labeled "Current" and I can click an arrow to apply old changes.

If I look at the history of the project, and click on a file from there, the current version is labeled "Your Version" (Read Only) and I cannot edit it directly.

Any idea whats going on?

[History directly from the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLfzB.png)

[History from the "Show History for Folder Dialog"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gxR1.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug. Editable panes were not implemented for the Local history of a directory.

Submitted https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-189367